# Imagens no domínio i.stack.imgur.com emitindo erro ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECT

Tags: bug, status-pronto

> Cross-post: [Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313779/198279)

Hoje notei que as imagens do dominio `i.stack.imgur.com` não carregam, ao olhar no console elas ficam redirecionando até que o navegador rejeite, como o site não esta aceitando imagens então vou fornecer o screen da tela em um site alternativo:

- https://ibb.co/kRNFMK

Todas imagens carregam em HTTPS inicialmente (o site usa isto), mas em seguida redirecionam para HTTP (sem segurança) e o loop fica infinito e claro causa erro de segurança também (quando eventualmente a imagem carrega).

Aparentemente não esta ocorrendo com todos usuários, eu também testei em uma janela anonima e não funcionou, ocorre o mesmo erro.

O erro também ocorreu no Firefox e também testei em janela anonima.

O problema começou hoje (2018-08-07) de tarde.

Comment: Eu ia perguntar isto no chat agora mesmo, se mais pessoas perceberam isto. Eu estou com erro também.

Comment: Confirmado aqui também em outras instâncias.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313725/140010

Comment: O seu já estou vendo, mas tem casos que ainda dá problema.

Comment: Alguns enroscam até agora.

Comment: É, as imagens sumiram aqui depois que usei CTRL SHIFT R pra atualizar a página.

Comment: Pra mim o erro também ocorre

Comment: Ao limpar os dados do navegador, as imagens voltaram para mim. Mas muitos estão relatando que somente limpar os dados do navegador não está resolvendo o problema.

Comment: @danieltakeshi exato, deve ser algo no CloudFront, talvez conflito de DNS ou algo assim

Comment: Marcando isso como [meta-tag:status-pronto] porque isso foi aparentemente corrigido. Se notarem esse problema novamente por favor me avise e então "reabrirei" a pergunta.

Answer (score 7):

Eu dei uma conferida lá no metão :

- [Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down)

Parece que eles estão tendo o mesmo problema também.

eles postaram o cabeçalho de resposta que o Imgurtá emitindo:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 15:13:49 GMT
Expires: Wed, 15 Aug 2018 15:13:49 GMT
Location: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yufyl.jpg
Server: nginx
Age: 8570
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 26bf46825c6bd12542772bad5a4d97b5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: jdUTshS_K0gqJp0E0TWmQ7CUh3mbm0MdiDGSO4wJt3pKhgf9lhWc7g==
```

Pelo que eu entendo o próprio imgur tá gerando um loop de redirecionamento pra a url da imagem.